# upgrade exchange 2003 to 2013

Tags: windows, exchange-2003, migration, exchange-2013

to go from exchange 2003 to 2013, do I have to upgrade to 2010 first, then from 2010 to 2013?
or there is any way to install the 2013 server, export stuff from 2003 server, import it into the 2013 server?

Additional info: We are migrating from an old server to a new server and we have about 75gb in db, 20 gb in archived pst's, and 100 users.

Comment: You could also remove 2003 and do a "fresh" install of 2013 - it might be less work than doing interim upgrades. Also, get someone familiar with these upgrades to help you, they aren't particularly easy. Also, consider O365. For smaller businesses (<50) it's a lot less maintenance/hardware/support than doing Exchange in-house.

Comment: Don't forget about things like Public Folders, 3rd party software that might be in use, client versions, virtualization, etc. in your process.

Comment: to Chris S:   If I uninstall 2003, then I install 2013, I should have to export, then remove all the users' mailboxes before uninstalling 2003, then recreate again all mailboxes and import everything after installing 2013, wouldn't this cause a lot of downtime?  Do you foresee other problems besides extended downtime?

Answer (score 3):

> do I have to upgrade to 2010 first, then from 2010 to 2013?

Yes. This is basically the price of not upgrading for a long time - and then hoping MS would care about it. 2 generations is the biggest supported. So, you need an interim step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to follow 2003->>-2007/2010->>-2013 migration as Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2013 is not directly supported.